# Parse only specific text/int

Tags: c#, new-operator

So i need some help with this.
I have an server-log where i need to filter out the error codes (404) from the log.
What i have so far cuts the error codes from the log but it still also displays the succesful connection codes (200) which i don't want.
I'm new to c# so any help is needed.

This is what i have:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;            
    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(filename);
    string value = filename;
    while (!streamreader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string data = bestand.ReadLine();   
        // Split the data to keep only the error codes
        string[] errorcodeArray = data.Split('"');
        string trim = Regex.Replace(errorcodeArray[2], @"", "");
        // Trim to keep only the 3 figure codes
        trim = trim.Substring(0, trim.IndexOf(" ") + 5);
        txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + data;
        txtError.Text += Environment.NewLine + trim;
        // Couldn't get the 404's out of this.
    }
    streamreader.Close();
```

Log-sample:

```
109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-" 
109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "almhuette-raith.at/administrator" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-" 
46.72.177.4     - - [12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide some sample data.

Comment: May bey should add the log file format also.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide data present in bestandsnaam and it will be great if you write your comments in english

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect most of the code here isn't really relevant - it doesn't matter how you *get* the string - only what you do with it. It would be really helpful if you'd provide a [mcve], along with sample inputs and what you expect the outputs to be. Also, if the comments are useful at all, it would be best to translate them into English. (And if they're not useful, remove them from the question.)

Comment: Log example:  109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "http://almhuette-raith.at/administrator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
46.72.177.4 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"

Comment: @OmeD: edit your question and put new informations there, nicely formatted. Also, where are the 404?

Comment: If you showed your expected output too, that'd make sure that people give the answer you're after.

Comment: I cant edit post so I will do it like this: What I want is to only dispay the 404 codes to the txtError.text

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(/*path*/);
var result = lines.Select(x=> Regex.Replace(x, @"HTTP/1.1"" \d+ ", @"HTTP/1.1"" "));
```

It will filter out all codes.
For just 200 and 404:

```
var result = lines.Select(x=> Regex.Replace(x, @"HTTP/1.1"" (200|404) ", @"HTTP/1.1"" "));
```

Comment: The x in:(x, @"HTTP/1.1"" (200|404) ", @"HTTP/1.1"" ")); has an error where it says it cannot convert char to string.

Comment: 'lines' should be IEnumerable<string> not string

Comment: What if it isn't always "HTTP/1.1"?

Comment: He mentions he does _not_ want the 200's.

Comment: It will not be filtered of course. But this will work for his logs, which partially, if not entirely solves his task. Does not want - I provided example which will cut that 200 from string.

Comment: Is this a good implementation?: var lines = File.ReadAllLines(data);
    var result = lines.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"HTTP/1.1"" \d+ ", 
    @"HTTP/1.1"" ")); and then: txtError.Text += Environment.NewLine + result;

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only want the "404" codes, and you don't show any of these in your example. if they are the same format this should work:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
var rows = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
var results = rows.Where(r => r.Split('"')[2].Trim().StartsWith("404"));
```

If the log file is very large and you don't want to read it all in one go, you should do the test in your loop. Here is a complete example of how to do it in a loop:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string data;
//using a string builder to concat strings is much more efficient
StringBuilder sbLog = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
{
   while ((data = file.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      if (data.Split('"')[2].Trim().StartsWith("404"))
      {
         sbLog.Append(data + Environment.NewLine);
         sbError.Append(data.Split('"')[2].Trim().Substring(0, 3) + Environment.NewLine);
      }
   }                
}

txtLog.Text = sbLog.ToString();
txtError.Text += sbError.ToString();
```

Comment: It says there are invalid character in path when i try to open the log file.

Comment: The "invalid character in path" is a whole different issue you will have to resolve. I have added a loop example for you. Did you initialize filename?